# Вычисление чисел фибоначи, где каждый отдельный уровень рекурсии вычисляется в отдельном процессе

Tags: c, числа-фибоначчи, fork

Надо рекурсивно посчитать чиста фибоначи, где каждый отдельный уровень рекурсии выполняется в отдельном процессе. Я написал программу, во время ее выполнения создается много процессов, на 24+ элементе( fib(24) и т.д.) почему-то не получается создать новый процесс, пишет, что pid < 0. Подскажите в чем проблемма и как ее решить.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

long fibonacci(int num) {
    if(num == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if(num == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if(pid == 0) {
            long res = fibonacci(num-2);
            exit(res);
        } else {
            long parentRes = fibonacci(num-1);
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            long res = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            return (parentRes + res);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("fib[%d] = %d\n", num, fibonacci(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Издеваетесь, да? :) Вы прикиньте количество создаваемых вами процессов... Например, чтоб посчитать всего лишь пятое число, запускаются 2 процесса - для третьего и четвертого. Для третьего - еще 2, 1 и 2; для 4 - тоже 2, 2 и 3. Итого уже 6. Но далее опять для третьего числа - 2 процесса... Короче, экспоненциальный рост. Если у вас такое дурацкое учебное задание - что поделать, оно не для больших значений... Применять сохранение вычисленных ранее чисел можно, но эта мемоизация из ДП может оказаться нарушением условия учебного задания...

Comment: Вы когда считаете через рекурсию стек переполняется в миг. А вы хотите отдельным потоком или ещё чего там

Comment: То есть, если полностью следовать заданию и не сохранять промежуточные значения, то решить эту задачу не получится?